# SQL Query (grouping the data)

Tags: mysql

I have a table column as a rating which has the following data

```
RATINGS
-----------
good
good-med
better 
better-med
best
best-high
worse
worse-med
best 
best
worse-med
good-med
```

The result I want for this is as:

```
RATING   NUMBER_OF_TIMES_RATED
good         3
best         4
better       2
worse        3
```

I want to write a query which groups as with all rating starting as good and gives the count having them.
For example good, good-med should be categorized as one and the get the output

I tried the following query but it did not work as I wanted to

```
Select RATING, count(RATING) as rate_num
from MENU
WHERE RATING like 'good%'
group by RATING
```

This gave me data as

```
RATING       rate_num
good          1
good-med      2
```

I also tried this query

```
Select RATING, count(RATING) as rate_num
from MENU
group by RATING
```

but didn't got expected results. I tried my best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to get the part of the rating before `-`.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(rating, '-', 1) AS rating_prefix, COUNT(*) AS rate_num
FROM menu
GROUP BY rating_prefix
```